# Custom expandable BaseExpandableListAdapter getGroupView or getChildView never gets called

Tags: android, expandablelistadapter

I have a `Viewpager` with 2 pages, on page 1 I fill a form and swipe to page 2 which has the `expandableList`, I am using a custom adapter as below.

I have included the expandable `listview` and another button inside a layout.

When I swipe to this new page, I see the empty layout along with the button, the expandable list never shows up.

I have checked and found out `getGroupCount` is returning a size equivalent to the size of the `arrayList` data. So it is not a problem of data being empty.

On further analysis, I figured out there `getGroupView` as well as the `getChildView` never gets called, I added some log statements to debug in those methods, they never get printed. However the constructor is being called, so is the `getGroupCoun` returning the correct values. Is my implementation correct?

```
public class FareStageExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter

{
private Context context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private ArrayList<TripTimings> data;
private SimpleDateFormat formatter;
private EditText fareField;
private TextView headerText;
private TextView childText;

public FareStageExpandableListAdapter(Context context,
        ArrayList<TripTimings> data)
{
    Log.d("FareStageExADapter", "Constructor called");
    this.context = context;
    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.data = data;
    this.formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");

}

@Override
public int getGroupCount()
{
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition)
{
    return data.size() - 1 - groupPosition;
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition)
{
    return data.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
{
    return data.get(groupPosition + childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition)
{
    return data.get(groupPosition).hashCode();
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
{
    return data.get(groupPosition + childPosition).hashCode() + 5;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds()
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parentView)
{
    TripTimings parent = data.get(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fareadd_expanded_parent,
                parentView, false);
    }
    headerText = ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.originText));

    Log.d("Setting header text ", parent.getStop().getStop_name());
    headerText.setText(parent.getStop().getStop_name());
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup childView)
{
    final TripTimings child = data.get(groupPosition + childPosition);
    if (convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fareadd_expanded_child,
                childView, false);
    }
    childText = ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.destinationText));

    Log.d("Setting child text ", child.getStop().getStop_name());
    childText.setText(child.getStop().getStop_name());

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

This is what happens when you are sleep deprived. There is nothing wrong with the code, except that the Adapter was never added to the expandablelistview